# Why can a bounty be awarded to a not accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Today I learned that bounties can be awarded to not accepted answers.

- Example: [Simplification of prefix notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035284/javascript-simplification-of-prefix-notation/59116531)

I struggle a bit to understand the point behind allowing this in the first place. So why is it possible to award a bounty to a not accepted answer?

Comment: Just to clarify that you know meaning of - "Accepted" : it means "helped OP the most"  - it does not mean answer is correct or good practice, it does not mean post is useful to anyone else, it does not mean the answer actually answers the question as written, it may even be actively malicious answer that OP liked for some reason (i.e. SQL injection because it can be done in one line of code).

Answer (score 17):

Anyone can create a bounty, not just the OP.

If I come across a great answer that helped me and it's not my question, should I be prevented from awarding a bounty just because the answer isn't accepted?

Also as only one answer can be accepted if we applied your rule only to bounties on questions that I asked, what if I want to reward two great answers? I can only accept one of them. Do I have to pointlessly shift the accept mark just to award the bounties I want?